# Inequality of norms for $H^\infty$ and $L^\infty$ spaces (part of a theorem on the Rudins' book Real and Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

In Rudin's book Real and Complex Analysis, in the eleventh chapter there is a theorem that states:

> To every $f\in H^\infty$ corresponds a function $f^*\in L^\infty (T),$ defined almost everywhere by $$f^*(e^{i\theta})=\lim_{r\to 1^-}f(re^{i\theta}).$$ The equality $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{\infty}=\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_{\infty}$ holds.

In the proof of the theorem for the equality $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{\infty}=\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_{\infty}$ there is stated that $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{\infty}\geq\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_{\infty}$ is obvious. My question is how to prove that $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{\infty}\geq\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_{\infty}$ holds?

In this question $H^\infty$ is the space of all holomorphic functions in the open unit ball $U$ equipped with the supremum norm, while $L^\infty$ is the space of all essentially bounded functions on  $T=\partial U$ normed by the essential supremum norm, relative to the Lebesgue measure, so $$\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_\infty=\inf\left\{ \alpha\vert m\left( \left( f^* \right)^{-1} \left(  \left[ \alpha,\infty \right)\right) \right)=0 \right\}$$ for $f^*:T\to \left[0, \infty \right).$

**My attempt:** Let suppose that $\left\Vert f\right\Vert_{\infty}<\left\Vert f^*\right\Vert_{\infty}.$ Then there exists an $\alpha '=\inf\left\{ \alpha\vert m\left( \left( f^* \right)^{-1} \left(  \left[ \alpha,\infty \right)\right) \right)=0 \right\}$ s.t. $\alpha'>\Vert f\Vert_\infty$, so $m\left( \left( f^* \right)^{-1} \left(  \left[ \Vert f\Vert_\infty,\infty \right)\right)\right)>0.$

How should I continue until a contradiction?

Comment: Use the [Poisson integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel)

Comment: Just do it directly. Since $\lvert f(re^{it})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$ for all $t$ and all $r \in [0,1)$, it follows that if the radial limit exists at some point, we have $\lvert f^{\ast}(e^{it})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$ there. Since the set where the radial limit doesn't exist is a null set, we're done.

Comment: @DanielFischer how do you connect $\vert f^*(e^{it})\vert$ with $\Vert f^*\Vert_\infty$?

Comment: Let $C$ be the set of points on the unit circle where the radial limit exists. For all $t$ with $e^{it} \in C$ we know $\lvert f^{\ast}(e^{it})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$. The complement of $C$ has measure $0$, so $m\bigl((f^{\ast})^{-1}([\alpha,+\infty))\bigr) = 0$ for all $\alpha > \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks mate!

Comment: @DanielFischer I have trouble in proving why $m(C^C)=0$ implies $m\left( \left( f^* \right)^{-1} \left(  \left[ \alpha,\infty \right)\right) \right)=0$ for all $\alpha >\Vert f\Vert\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C \subset T$ be the set where the radial limit
$$\lim_{r \to 1^-} f(re^{i\theta})$$
exists. By theorems 11.30 and 11.23, $m(T\setminus C) = 0$, and $f$ is the Poisson integral of $f^{\ast}$. On $T\setminus C$, we can define $f^{\ast}$ arbitrarily if we want an everywhere defined function $f^{\ast}$.

Since $\lvert f(re^{i\theta})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$ for $r \in [0,1)$, we have
$$\lvert f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta})\rvert = \lim_{r \to 1^-}\: \lvert f(re^{i\theta})\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$$
for all $e^{i\theta} \in C$.

Let $\alpha > \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$. Then
$$\bigl\{ e^{i\theta} : \lvert f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta})\rvert \geqslant \alpha \bigr\} \subset T\setminus C\,,$$
so this is a null set. Hence
$$(\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}, +\infty) \subset \bigl\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} : m\bigl(\bigl(\lvert f^{\ast}\rvert\bigr)^{-1}([\alpha, +\infty))\bigr) = 0\bigr\}$$
and consequently
$$\lVert f^{\ast}\rVert_{\infty} = \inf\: \bigl\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{R} : m\bigl(\bigl(\lvert f^{\ast}\rvert\bigr)^{-1}([\alpha, +\infty))\bigr) = 0\bigr\} \leqslant \inf\: (\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}, +\infty) = \lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\,.$$

[Note that $f^{\ast}$ is complex-valued, so we must consider $\bigl(\lvert f^{\ast}\rvert\bigr)^{-1}([\alpha,+\infty))$ and not $\bigl(f^{\ast}\bigr)^{-1}([\alpha,+\infty))$.]

Comment: I think that the notation $\left( f^* \right)^{-1} \left(  \left[ \alpha,\infty \right)\right)=0$ is correct since the Lebesgue measure is defined on T.

Comment: But we must look at the codomain. We need to know whether $\bigl\{ e^{i\theta} : \lvert f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta})\rvert \geqslant \alpha\bigr\}$ is a null set. The set $\bigl(f^{\ast}\bigr)^{-1}([\alpha,+\infty))$ is $\bigl\{ e^{i\theta} : f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta}) \in \mathbb{R} \land f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta}) \geqslant \alpha \bigr\}$. But unless $f^{\ast}$ is real-valued and takes only non-negative values, that set can have measure $0$ also for $\alpha < \lVert f^{\ast}\rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: $f^*$ is given with $f^*:T\to \left[0, \infty \right).$

Comment: $H^{\infty}$ is the space of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk, and for $f \in H^{\infty}$, $f^{\ast}$ is defined as the radial limit function of $f$. E.g. for $f(z) = z$ we have $f^{\ast}(e^{i\theta}) = e^{i\theta}$. Occasionally the image of $f^{\ast}$ is contained in $[0,\infty)$, but typically it isn't.